# Timezones in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I develop web-site with different events. And I want to show  event start time in user local time. And I don't know how do that.
I try to use this django app [django-easy-timezones](https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones). But it show time in UTC.
My settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

My template:

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
      {{ start_time|date:"H:i" }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

It's possible to do that without asking a timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three ways to accomplish this without directly asking the user; 1) use a client side application, 2) rely on geo-ip or 3) rely on browser proprietary location services.

**Option 1** would require something on the client side that fetchs the system timezone and returns it with a request. In javascript, you can fetch the timezone with a call to `getTimezoneOffset()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp.

**Option 2** would rely on the GeoIP database from maxmind. They have an FAQ on this very topic http://dev.maxmind.com/faq/how-can-i-determine-the-timezone-of-a-website-visitor

> The GeoIP2 City database similarly provides the time zone in the
>   location record. To find out how to access this, refer to the
>   documentation for your language’s GeoIP2 API.

**Option 3** requires utilization of each browser's proprietary geolocation technology.  Here's a link to how todo this with Mozilla https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/

Comment: There is another option user remote API. You can get the time zone by passing in the IP address.

http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php